# Como recibir parametros de conexion a base de datos desde un archivo configurable en C#

Tags: c#, sql

Me encuentro en el desarrollo de una aplicación para el control de flujo de personas en una institución medica, lo debemos implementar en dos anexos mas independientes de nuestra red. Por lo tanto cada implementación contara con su propia pc servidor y las pcs cliente. Mi consulta es la siguiente, ¿como puedo crear la opción de que los archivos de configuración, por ejemplo, los datos del SQL (ruta, usuario, pass, nombre de la db) se lean desde un archivo de configuración .ini o .txt? Para evitar una recompilación cada vez que necesite instalarlo en una nueva dependencia.
Por ejemplo:

```
[SQLDB] 
DB= XXXXX
```

Saludos cordiales!

Comment: la solucion es crear un archivo de configuracion xml app.config el cual esta disponible al crear los objetos, te dejo un link para que puedar darle una leida. [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://blog.submain.com/app-config-basics-best-practices/)

Answer (score 3):

En lo personal lo hago de la siguiente manera:

**Paso 1:** Corre tu programa y dirígete a `bin/Debug`, dentro de esa carpeta encontraras un archivo con extensión: `nombre_de_mi_programa.exe.config`, lo abres y debe de existir un código xml similar a este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Entonces lo editas para que quede así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="CharityManagement" connectionString="User ID=root; Password=; Host=localhost; Port=3306; Database=ventas;"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Y en la variable: **connectionString** debe de estar la configuración que necesitas, creo que se entiende viendo el ejemplo. Lo guardas para pasar al siguiente paso.

**Paso 2:** Crear un Modelo para acceder a los datos, te dejo el ejemplo de como lo hago yo:

```
namespace Modelos
{
    class Conexion
    {
        public static string Cn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CharityManagement"].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

La parte del `namespace` es depende te tu proyecto(pero supongo que ya lo sabes).

**Paso 3:** Pasamos a utilizar nuestra conexión, Te dejo una clase completa:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Modelos;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using DevComponents.DotNetBar;
using System.Data;

namespace facturacion.Controladores
{
    class CUsuarios
    {
        internal static String table = "usuarios";
        public static bool Insertar(MUsuario objeto, DevComponents.DotNetBar.Metro.MetroForm form)
        {

            MySqlConnection SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(Conexion.Cn);
            try
            {
                SqlCon.Open();
                string query001 = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(nombre,ci,direccion,telefono,tipo,estado,cuenta,contraseña) Values(@nombre,@ci,@direccion,@telefono,@tipo,@estado,@cuenta,@contraseña)";
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query001, SqlCon);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", objeto.nombre);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ci", objeto.ci);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", objeto.direccion);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono", objeto.telefono);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", objeto.tipo);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", objeto.estado);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuenta", objeto.cuenta);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contraseña", objeto.contraseña);


                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    ToastNotification.Show(form, "Usuario Creada Correctamente", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.ok, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Green), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
                    SqlCon.Close();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ToastNotification.Show(form, "Usuario no pudo ser Creada", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
                    SqlCon.Close();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                ToastNotification.Show(form, e.Message, global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopLeft));
                return false;
            }
        }
        public static bool Editar(int id, MUsuario objeto, DevComponents.DotNetBar.Metro.MetroForm form)
        {

            MySqlConnection SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(Conexion.Cn);
            try
            {
                SqlCon.Open();
                string query001 = "UPDATE " + table + " SET nombre=@nombre,ci=@ci,direccion=@direccion,telefono=@telefono,tipo=@tipo,estado=@estado,cuenta=@cuenta,contraseña=@contraseña where id=@id;";
                Console.WriteLine(query001);
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query001, SqlCon);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", objeto.nombre);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ci", objeto.ci);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", objeto.direccion);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono", objeto.telefono);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", objeto.tipo);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", objeto.estado);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuenta", objeto.cuenta);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contraseña", objeto.contraseña);
                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    ToastNotification.Show(form, "Usuario Editada Correctamente", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.ok, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Green), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
                    SqlCon.Close();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ToastNotification.Show(form, "El Usuario no pudo ser Editado", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
                    SqlCon.Close();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                ToastNotification.Show(form, e.Message, global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopLeft));
                return false;
            }
        }
        public static bool Eliminar(int id, DevComponents.DotNetBar.Metro.MetroForm form)
        {
            MySqlConnection SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(Conexion.Cn);
            try
            {
                SqlCon.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("UPDATE " + table + " SET estado='disable' where id='" + id + "';"), SqlCon);
                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    ToastNotification.Show(form, " El usuario se elimino correctamente", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.ok, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Green), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
                    SqlCon.Close();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ToastNotification.Show(form, "El usuario no se pudo eliminar", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
                    SqlCon.Close();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ToastNotification.Show(form, e.Message, global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopLeft));
                return false;
            }

        }


        public static DataTable Mostrar()
        {
            DataTable DtResultado = new DataTable("usuario");
            MySqlConnection SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(Conexion.Cn);
            MySqlCommand SqlDat = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM " + table + " where estado='enable' ORDER BY nombre DESC;"), SqlCon);
            SqlCon.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dr = SqlDat.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            DtResultado.Load(dr);
            dr.Close();
            SqlDat.Dispose();
            SqlCon.Close();
            return DtResultado;
        }
        public static DataTable Buscar(String buscarPor, String variableAbuscar)
        {
            DataTable DtResultado = new DataTable("usuario");
            MySqlConnection SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(Conexion.Cn);
            MySqlCommand SqlDat = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT  * FROM " + table + " where estado='enable' AND " + buscarPor + " like '%" + variableAbuscar + "%' ORDER BY  nombre DESC;"), SqlCon);
            SqlCon.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dr = SqlDat.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            DtResultado.Load(dr);
            dr.Close();
            SqlDat.Dispose();
            SqlCon.Close();
            return DtResultado;
        }
    }
}
```

El copiar y pegar no creo que te funcione, ya que algunos componentes son propios pero creo que el ejemplo te servirá, la conexión esta en: `MySqlConnection SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(Conexion.Cn);`

Answer (score 1):

Si esta tarea también se puede realizar de la siguiente manera:

```
// Leer una clave de un fichero INI
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetPrivateProfileString
(
     string nombre_seccion,        // Señala el nombre de la Seccion
     string nombre_clave,        // Señala el nombre de la LLave
     string por_defecto,        // Señala el string default
     string destino_buffer, // Señala el destino del buffer
     int tamano,            // Tamaño del destino del buffer
     string archivo_inicializacion // Señala el nombre del archivo de la iniciaclizacion. 
);

/// <summary> Explicacion de la Funcion. 
/// Devuelve el valor de una clave de un fichero INI
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fichero">El Fichero INI</param>
/// <param name="seccion">La seccion que se quiere leer</param>
/// <param name="clave">La clave</param>
/// <param name="por_defecto"> Valor opcional que devolverá si no se encuentra la clave.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public string ObtenerValorClave(string archivo, string seccion, string clave, string por_defecto)
{
    int retorno;
    string valor_retorno;
    valor_retorno = new string(' ', 255);
    retorno = GetPrivateProfileString(seccion, clave, por_defecto, valor_retorno, valor_retorno.Length, archivo);
    if (retorno == 0)
       return por_defecto;
    else
       return valor_retorno.Substring(0, retorno);
}
```

> Suponiendo que tu archivo tenga la siguiente estructura:

```
[SQLDB]
Servidor = TuServidor
DB = TuDataBase
User = TuUsuario
Password = TuClave
```

---

Entonces de esté modo construyes tu cadena de conexión de la siguiente manera:

```
string seccion = "SQLDB";
string ruta_rchivo = @"C:/tuArchivo.ini";
string conectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User Id={2};Password={3}",
                                   ObtenerValorClave(ruta_archivo, seccion, "Servidor", ""),
                                   ObtenerValorClave(ruta_archivo, seccion, "DB", ""),
                                   ObtenerValorClave(ruta_archivo, seccion, "User", ""),
                                   ObtenerValorClave(ruta_archivo, seccion, "Password", ""));
```

Y luego pues ya si deseas esa cadena de conexión que has construido, puedes guardarla en el `App.Config` de tu Sistema.

**Nota:** Por motivos de seguridad, no te recomiendo que almacenes claves de usuarios en estos archivos, por lo demás no le veo problema. 
Espero te sirva. Saludos!